# How to create popup windows in html

Tags: html

I want to know how the pop up windows integrated into websites are built. I am trying to create one for my websites but i don't really know it is created whether they are plugins or not. Any help as to how to go about it.
Below is an example of what i want to do.

[image]

Comment: An easy solution is to just use css to create a new HTML element with position: fixed; Here's some information on other options.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use hotjar.com to put a feedback box in your page, there is a lot of services that provides this feature, but hotjar gets the job done

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Beginner! To make a pop-up like the one you provided, you would need to write backend code (Node.JS, PHP, Python, etc.). But for just a simple info pop-up with a button that activates the pop-up refer to this jsfiddle I created:

https://jsfiddle.net/d706dyg7/1/

```
$("#whateverid").click(function(){
    //whatever code
});
```

That mean when that element is clicked blah happens.

Hope that helps,
Ben A.K.A BlackSky

P.S. If you want a solution in pure javascript and not jQuery just let me know and I will edit my fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm like .. 10 years late. But for anyone still wondering I thought I could be of some help!
If you want to do this using ONLY html and css (using a framework in visual studio like ASP.NET) for example.. here's what I did:
First, I made sure I had multiple "divs" in my code. For me specifically, I had two main ones. The first one whose id="main", and another whose id="popup" with the 'visible' property initially set to 'false' for the popup div.

Then, on whichever event you're looking for (button click for example) you'll simply set main.Visible = false and popup.Visible = true, then you could have more buttons in your popup (yes, no, cancel, confirm, etc.) which do the exact same thing, but in reverse!

The most important thing to make sure of is that you have the 'runat="server"' property in your divs so that you can access them in your CS code

Hope this was helpful! :)

Answer (score -1):

Your looking for something called a modal. Depending how you wrote your HTML there are different ways of approaching this issue.

If your wrote your website in Plain HTML you can use the following tutorial to create one

www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/amp/

However if you wrote your website with a library such as Bootstrap they have built in pre made modules that you can attach to your cpde. These can Ben found in the library's documentation.